# Remove controller and method from URL Path in .Net Core 6.0

Tags: url, .net-core, methods, routes, controller

Could any one please help me out with situation.

I have project whereby I want to remove each Controller and Method from my url path every time i request.
example right now my every time url looks like below

[www.mywebsite.com/Account/View](http://www.mywebsite.com/Account/View)

but i want to remove /Account/View from url

Comment: If you want to change the default route of action,you can try to use `Route` attribute,here is a n official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0) about routing.

Comment: not its not like that....even if i use attribute it will show the details in url path

Comment: Hi, Can any one please advice me on this

Answer (score 0):

You could try [TempData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-8.0#tempdata)

Where ever you are trying to get the properties you wish to pass as parameters... example post them to a route in a ViewModel and pass them to the next route

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IAction PageOne(PageViewModel model)
    {
        // Store the property
        TempData["MyProp"] = model.CollectedProperty;

        return RedirectToAction("PageTwo");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IAction PageTwo(){
        PageTwoViewModel model = new PageTwoViewModel();

        // Grab the property
        model.PropertyWasPassed = (string)TempData["MyProp"];
    }
```

*Note that TempData only lasts for 1 request and then the data is no longer available.